# How to back in Tabbar viewcontrollers specifice view index after a action

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

[image]

This is my TabBarViewController.i want to back in SourceTableViewController after completing the action transfer of FundTransferViewController.Any help?

Comment: [tabBarObj setSelectedIndex:1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to go to another tab after completing action in another tab, this will help:

```
[self.tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:no of your index];
```

so if SourceTableViewController index number in tabbar is 2, than

```
[self.tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:2];
```

call this in your transfer action in `FundTransferViewController` class.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
[tabBarControllerObj setSelectedIndex:1]; //Change index value as per ur need
```

Answer (score 0):

please Try this:

```
 [tabBar setSelectedViewController:[[tabBar viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index]];// where index is the index of view controller where you want to switch back.
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: this is giving me this error UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected